# How to trigger a build with a shelveset in TFS 2015 using REST API

Tags: rest, tfs, tfsbuild

I have a PowerShell script (Start-TargetBuild.ps1) that I call from a 2015 vNext team build.  This script uses the REST interface to kick off another team build.  The script works fine except when I attempt to add a shelveset to the initial build.  In that case I get the following error:

```
Start-TargetBuild : Error in REST API call! 
At \\chdfileserver01\IT\PowerShell_Library\TeamBuild-Launch.ps1:426 char:2 
+ Start-TargetBuild 
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
+ CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException 
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: build","typeName":"System.ArgumentNullException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561 
934e089","typeKey":"ArgumentNullException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}.ErrorDetails.Message,Start-TargetBuild
```

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To trigger a build with a shelveset you should use **sourceBranch**  parameter in the [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#queue-a-build) body.

```
sourceBranch: "The shelveset name","The shelveset owner"
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick.  That leads to the next question - how do I access the shelveset name/owner from PowerShell in a team build?  I can see in the "Get sources" step where the shelveset is unshelved into the build workspace. So, obviously that information is communicated to the build.

Comment: @LS-1 To get the shelveset info you could use  the [Get list of shelvesets](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfvc/shelvesets) rest api which will return detail info of shelvesets. To the owner, suggest you to use `uniqueName: "fabrikamfiber16@hotmail.com"`

Comment: Never mind my previous comment.  I see the shelveset information is in the environment variables passed to the team build; $env:BUILD_SOURCETFVCSHELVESET

Answer (score 0):

For the reference, the full body json should be:

```
$body = '
{ 
        "definition": {
            "id": 10000
        }, 
        "sourceBranch": "ShelvesetName;Domain\\UserName"
}
'
```